# Leer un valor en un archivo plano txt

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema quiero leer un txt y leerlo como si fuera un json para así consultar una fecha. Este es el txt

```
[
{
    "Process": "filecompressor_wf",
    "Number": 1,
    "ExecutionDateStart": "2020-12-11T18:55:49.5399519-06:00",
    "MigrateDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "ExecutionDateEnd": "2020-12-11T18:55:58.9045763-06:00",
    "Events": [
        {
            "Service": 1,
            "Output": "Iniciando ejecuci¢n de carga de documentos con la configuraci¢n:\r\nRuta ra¡z de documentos XML: C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\r\nServicio: Issuance\r\nMes de carga: 1\r\nD¡as de carga: 1\r\nClientes a procesar: todos\r\nM ximos procesos Managers para carga de d¡as: 1\r\nM ximos procesos Uploaders por Manager para carga de clientes por d¡a: 1\r\nEs migraci¢n local: SI\r\nHabilitaci¢n de fusi¢n de ZIP's hist¢ricos: NO\r\nForzar descarga desde FileShare: SI\r\nSAS FileShare: ?st=2020-12-12T00%3A38%3A58Z&se=2021-12-02T00%3A38%3A00Z&sp=rcwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=okQ4nDWxyDT4KY6OG5D5S6P1jqIkEHJlxrCZPAvjeJ8%3D\r\n\r\n=========================================================================\r\nIniciando la descarga de archivos desde FS hac¡a directorio C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\\20200101\r\nEjecutando azcopy con comando: copy \"https://garostandardscus.file.core.windows.net/drived/data/_OUT/2020/20200101/*??st=2020-12-12T00%3A38%3A58Z&se=2021-12-02T00%3A38%3A00Z&sp=rcwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=okQ4nDWxyDT4KY6OG5D5S6P1jqIkEHJlxrCZPAvjeJ8%3D\" \"C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\\20200101\" --recursive\r\nEjecutando azcopy con comando: copy \"https://garostandardscus.file.core.windows.net/drived/data/_pdf/2020/20200101/*??st=2020-12-12T00%3A38%3A58Z&se=2021-12-02T00%3A38%3A00Z&sp=rcwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=okQ4nDWxyDT4KY6OG5D5S6P1jqIkEHJlxrCZPAvjeJ8%3D\" \"c:\\users\\admin-xml\\documents\\pruebas\\data\\_PDF\\2020\\20200101\" --recursive\r\nLa informaci¢n de total de archivos no est  disponible.\r\nLa informaci¢n de total de archivos completados no est  disponible.\r\nLa informaci¢n de total de archivos con falla no est  disponible.\r\nLa informaci¢n de total de archivos saltados no est  disponible.\r\nLa informaci¢n de estatus general de carga no est  disponible.\r\nProceso finalizado\r\n=========================================================================\r\n\r\n\r\nIniciando proceso de directorio: C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\\20200101\r\n\r\nComenzando la carga del directorio: C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\\20200101\r\nGUID MASTER: 20201211185550_202001_ae8b191b-f19a-4cd8-9b99-7900971f8669\r\nNo existen documentos v lidos para carga.\r\n\r\nFinalizando proceso de directorio: C:\\Users\\admin-xml\\Documents\\Pruebas\\data\\_OUT\\2020\\20200101\r\n",
            "Success": true,
            "Docs_Total": 0,
            "Zips_Success": 0,
            "Zips_Error": 0,
            "Zips_Total": 0,
            "Docs_Success": 0,
            "Docs_Error": 0,
            "GuidMaster": null,
            "ExecutionDateStart": "2020-12-11T18:55:49.6807756-06:00",
            "ExecutionDateEnd": "2020-12-11T18:55:58.8577015-06:00",
            "TaxIdFilter": "",
            "IncludeTaxIdFilter": false,
            "IsLocalMigration": true,
            "IsMergeZips": false,
            "IsDownloadFSActivated": true,
            "ManagersCount": 1,
            "UploadersPerManager": 1
        }
    ],
    "Type": 2
}
```

]

Y necesito consultar el valor de "ExecutionDateEnd". el problema es que esto se escribe en un txt plano y no se como entrar a encontrar el valor que requiero.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Comment: y que intentaste?

Comment: Cree una clase para serializarlo con Newtonsoft y de ahí volver a desearilizar pero me dice que no es correcto.

Comment: que no es correcto que cosa?  por favor, completa tu pregunta con lo que intentaste y los errores...

Comment: si ya tienes el texto en json serializa el json en una clase c# y busca la fecha que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

1. Crea una clase con las propiedades de tu archivo

```
public class Archivo
{
   
    public string Process { get; set; }


 
    public string Number { get; set; }

 
    public string ExecutionDateStart { get; set; }


    public string MigrateDate { get; set; }

  
    public string ExecutionDateEnd { get; set; }

   

    public string Type { get; set; }



}
```

2. Deserializar tu archivo con esa clase

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string ubicacion = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,"archivo","archivo.txt");
    
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ubicacion);
        
    var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
    
    Console.WriteLine(result2.ExecutionDateEnd);
    System.Console.ReadKey();
    
}
```